# NSPredicate against nested values in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, sprite-kit

I have an NSArray of SKNodes, and am trying to use an NSPredicate to sort on the location.y values of the SKNodes using a predicate filter.  I am trying the following, but at runtime I am getting the 'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key y'  So, I assume I have to do something else to filter on a subcompnent of the object?  IS this possible?

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position.y"
                                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *results = [myarrayofsknodes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Comment: The point's x/y fields are not accessible via KVC because CGPoint is not an object (id) but a C struct. Try to use a comparator that gives you two objects (the nodes) and then compare their position.y in the comparator block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by LearnCocos2D is correct. However, you can sort other ways.

```
NSArray *original; // Populate this elsewhere
NSArray *results = [original sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(MyObject *obj1, MyObject *obj2) {
    if (obj1.position.y==obj2.position.y) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if (obj1.position.y < obj2.position.y) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}];
```